# Get logged in username in wordpress url

Tags: url-rewriting, users, urls, site-url

I want to get the username of the logged in users in the URL of my wordpress site. Like if user: **arvind** is logged in, I want to get the url as **'www.wp.com/arvind'** or **'www.wp.com?user=arvind'**.

Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you are looking for.

```
add_action("template_redirect", 'template_redirect');
function template_redirect() {
 global $wp;    
     if(is_user_logged_in() && !isset($_GET['user'])){
    $current_user=  get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
    wp_redirect(add_query_arg(array('user'=>$current_user->user_login),home_url($wp->request)));
    die();
}
}
```

Comment: I will try it soon.

Comment: My url is "http://localhost/wp351/", but it redirected to "localhost/wp351/wp351/admin?user=1"

Comment: I have edited url and it is working now.

Comment: Is there any way so that I can rewrite my url "http://localhost/wp351/?user=arvind" to "http://localhost/wp351/arvind"